# Property does not seem to work the right way

Tags: python, class, properties, assert, getter

I can't figure out why the last assert is not working. The error message, "type object 'Student' has no attribute 'name'", confuses me even more, because Student has an attribute called name. Any solutions?

```
class Student:

def __init__(self, name, imt_name, semester):
    self.name = name
    self.imt_name = imt_name
    self.semester = semester

def get_name(self):
    return self.name

def __str__(self):
    return ("{} [{}] in Semester {}".format(self.name, self.imt_name, self.semester))

x = property(get_name)

#asserts and test
assert type(Student) is type

student_horst = Student("Horst", "horst99", 2)
assert student_horst.name == "Horst"
assert student_horst.imt_name == "horst99"
assert student_horst.semester == 2

student_horst.semester = 3
assert student_horst.semester == 3

#this one is not working!
assert isinstance(getattr(Student, "name"), property)
```

Comment: Assuming indentation fixes; you haven't named the property name, you've named it x. The *instance* has an attribute name, but the class doesn't.

Comment: so it would fix the problem if i would name the property "name"?

Comment: Then you'd have a different problem, because the getter for name accesses the name attribute, which calls the getter for name, which ...

Comment: so changing the parameters in init and renaming property would fix it

Comment: Yes; conventionally the backing attribute is named with a leading underscore, _name.

Comment: Thank you sir! Really dumb mistake from me ._.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

name was never a property, x was

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name # this is an attribute

    @property
    def name(self): # property
        return self._name

    def get_name(self):
        return self._name

    x = property(get_name) # x is a property not _name

student = Student('Horst')
print(student._name, student.name, student.x, sep='\n')
assert isinstance(getattr(Student, 'name'), property)
assert isinstance(getattr(Student, 'x'), property)
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if instance has a given attribute(by name) you need to use the [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) function, as follows:

```
assert hasattr(student_horst, "name")
```

Comment: You've also, more importantly, changed the argument to the function. That's what actually makes the difference.